# If you don't say bismillah before eating and shaytan eats with you why don't you see the food decreasing?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, shaitan

Like how the hadith were if you dont say bismillah shaytan eats with you, and most people know this

Comment: It would be better if you cited the related hadith.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the djinn/shaytans eat like human beings, the djinn are made out of a certain form of flame, you cannot imagine how they are made, or even how they eat.